# Perform an action when map finished with async function

Tags: angular, rxjs6

In this effect I’m getting product and if this product has “childProducts” it becomes array of products.

Then, on the map function there is a pop up modal for each of the products in the array.

I want to make some action when the map is finished with all products.

How it be achieved?

```
    @Effect()
    selectProductPage$ = this.actions$.ofType<SelectProduct>(OrderActionTypes.SelectProduct).pipe(
      map(action => action.payload),
      switchMap((product) => {
        const allTests = [product, ...(product.product.childProducts || [])].map(cloneDeep);
        return from(allProducts);
      }),
      map((product: any) => {
        // pop up modal for each product
      })
    );
```

Comment: this kind of depends a lot on how the modals are instantiated. but this seems like a very odd approach in any event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **tap** rxjs operators to do some action after "map" finished.

So your code will become like

```
@Effect()
    selectProductPage$ = this.actions$.ofType<SelectProduct>OrderActionTypes.SelectProduct).pipe(
      map(action => action.payload),
      switchMap((product) => {
        const allTests = [product, ...(product.product.childProducts || [])].map(cloneDeep);
        return from(allProducts);
      }),
      map((product: any) => {
        // pop up modal for each product
      }),
      tap((result) => this.finishRequest(result)) // HERE IS THE CHANGE
    );
```

Comment: It hit the tap N times as the number of products before raising the modal window in map function...